# Using form values as input to a PHP function to dynamically fill a third form field

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic

Suppose the simple three input form below. Using the values of lat and lon I need to run a PHP function (already written) that creates the value I want in sitename. The current form action already works just fine, and does something completely different than my question.

```
<form name="w3Balltrak" class="feedbackform" action="readyget.pl" method="post"
<input type="text" id='lat' name='lat' value='' />
<input type="text" id='lon' name='lon' value='' />
<input type="text" id='sitename' name='sitename' value='' />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" /> 
</form>
```

My problem is I don't know how to set the value of the sitename to the output of my PHP function. The function works great, a call to it in PHP would look like this 'getWX($lat, $lon)' and the return would look like this 'MCI'.

How do I make the default value of sitename MCI immediately after the user enters a value in lon but before he hits the submit button at the end of the form?

I hope I asked this well enough for someone to understand and answer.

Comment: Sounds like a job for asynchronous HTTP requests or Ajax. Have you looked into that?

Comment: yes as andre said use a $.ajax function and call it from a change function on the lat and long field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i understood your question .. your answer would be ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// wait until the document ist ready.. otherwise the 2 ids dont exist in this moment
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    // on every change in the input fields send a request to the php
    $('#lat, #lon').live('change', function(){
        $.get("test.php", { lat: $('#lat').val(), lon: $('#lon').val() },
           function(data){
             $('#sitename').val(data);
        });            
    });
});
</script>
```

and in the test.php file

```
<?php
// if the 2 fields are not empty ... join them and return the result
if(!empty($_GET['lat']) && !empty($_GET['lon'])){
    $result = $_GET['lat'] . $_GET['lon'];
}
echo $result; 
?>
```

$result will then be what the jQuery function recives as "data"

Comment: After playing with this for an hour or so I realize I'm going to need a little more hand holding. I've installed a link to Google's jQuery, put the jQuery.get into my page between <script> tags, but I don't how the lat and lon values get to it, or how the php part works.

Comment: put the code into a document.ready function .... $ is abbreviation of JQuery in case you pass it to the document.ready function($) as a parameter..

change function means on every change of the 2 input fields
with .val() you get the latest value of the input fields
the function(data) is waiting for the result of the php...... the php file is just checking if both fields are together and joins them... echos the result and sends it back to the jQuery function as data variable

Comment: I think I can use this to make it work. Looking over the jQuery stuff I understand what it's doing now. Thank you so much for the help, hell, thanks for the code man.

Comment: My jQuery looks like this; <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#longitude").change(function () {
   //alert( $('#latitude').val());
   //alert( $('#longitude').val());  
   $.get("nearestAirport.php", { lat: $("#latitude").val(), lon: $("#longitude").val() }, 
    function(data,status,xhr){
     alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status + "\nxhr: " + xhr);
     $("#wx").val(data);
            });
  });
 }); 
 </script> But the alert doesn't return any data, it does say success and xhr: [object Object]

Comment: what are you returning with the php function? a string a object a array... also try not to allert ... better use console.info(data); and dont put it together with other paramseters.. i mean make a console.info for every row without makeing concats like this **("Data: " + data)** .... just (data) .... in this case you get a view of how the data is organized

Comment: The return from the function is a simple string such as "MCI / 42km".  I don't understand jQuery well enough to understand the syntax you want me to add. <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
  $("#longitude").change(function () {  
   var lat = $("#latitude").val(); var lon = $("#longitude").val();
   $.get("http://arhab.org/nearestAirport.php", { lat: $("#latitude").val(), lon: $("#longitude").val() }, 
    function(data,status,xhr){
     $("#wx").val(data);
     alert(" Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status + "\nxhr: " + xhr);
            });});}); 
  </script>

Comment: try to change the first line of jquery to **jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {**

Comment: What I did not understand about the above code was in the PHP function itself. In order to work a call to the function must be made. In my case I made the call at the bottom of the function, after the close "}". Then went I used the jQuery call it all worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to communicate with PHP without submitting the form, you need to use ajax. Have you heard of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/), which provides a convenient way for ajax queries?

I would basically append an event handler to watch out for changes of `lat` and `lon` and if both are set, request the server side php script via ajax.

Does this help you?